# Confidence interval for standard deviation of means

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, standard-error

I am doing some image analysis which [involves](https://aapm.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/acm2.13719):

1. Creating a grid of square objects
2. Calculating mean pixel values in each grid (m)
3. Calculating standard deviation of the mean pixel values (s)
4. Multiplying the standard deviation by 3.29 to obtain a contrast detectability value

This is then repeated for different object sizes, and the standard deviation can be plotted against object size. I'd like to show error bars on this graph, or quote uncertainty, but am unsure of how to proceed.

I could calculate a standard error from s and the number of objects in the grid, but am not sure if I should be accounting for the underlying standard deviation from the number of pixels in each object as well somehow?